# Mapbox.js exclusive layer switcher toggle

Tags: javascript, mapbox

Asking for help. My mapbox.js code is all fine except I'm unable to finish the one last thing: I want the toggle to work in a way so that only one layer/button is active at a time. So that when a new button is pushed the other one goes silent.

Probably a pretty simple thing for someone familiar with js. Note that there both tilelayers, tooltips interaction and legends coupled with the buttons.

If someone could lead me in the right direction I'd be so grateful. Code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Russian Waterways</title>
  <script src='http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.6.4/mapbox.js'></script>
  <link href='http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.6.4/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />


  <style>
    body { margin:0; padding:0; }
    #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<style>
#map-ui {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}

#map-ui a {
    font: normal 13px/18px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #3C4E5A;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #BBB;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    min-width: 138px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#map-ui a:hover {
    background: #ECF5FA;
}

#map-ui li:last-child a {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}

#map-ui li:first-child a {
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

#map-ui a.active {
    background: #3887BE;
    border-color: #3887BE;
    border-top-color: #FFF;
    color: #FFF;
}
</style>
<ul id='map-ui'></ul>
<div id='map'></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'maxmeles.map-a2km8b40', { zoomControl: false }).setView([56.54, 52.16], 4);
var ui = document.getElementById('map-ui');

addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('maxmeles.Spb-Moscow'), L.mapbox.gridLayer('maxmeles.Spb-Moscow'),'Petersburg-Moscow', 1);
addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('maxmeles.Astrakan-MoscowLegend'), L.mapbox.gridLayer('maxmeles.Astrakan-MoscowLegend'),'Moscow-Astrakhan', 2);
addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('maxmeles.SPB-ASTRAKHANLEGENDRED'), L.mapbox.gridLayer('maxmeles.SPB-ASTRAKHANLEGENDRED'),'Petersburg-Astrakhan', 3);
addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('maxmeles.Perm-MoscowLegend'), L.mapbox.gridLayer('maxmeles.Perm-MoscowLegend'),'Moscow-Perm', 4);
addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('maxmeles.moskvakazan'), L.mapbox.gridLayer('maxmeles.moskvakazan'),'Moscow-Kazan', 5);
addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('maxmeles.DonLegend'), L.mapbox.gridLayer('maxmeles.DonLegend'),'Rostov-Astrakhan', 6);
addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('maxmeles.DneprRed'), L.mapbox.gridLayer('maxmeles.DneprRed'),'Kiev-Odessa', 7);
addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('maxmeles.RedTulceaIstanbul'), L.mapbox.gridLayer('maxmeles.RedTulceaIstanbul'),'Tulcea-Istanbul', 8);  
addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('maxmeles.SPB-ROSTOVLEGENDRED'), L.mapbox.gridLayer('maxmeles.SPB-ROSTOVLEGENDRED'),'Rostov-Petersburg', 9);
addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('maxmeles.Rostov-MoscowLegend'), L.mapbox.gridLayer('maxmeles.Rostov-MoscowLegend'),'Rostov-Moscow', 10);
addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('maxmeles.Trans-Siberian'), L.mapbox.gridLayer('maxmeles.Trans-Siberian'),'Trans-Siberian', 11);




function addLayer(layer, gridlayer, name, zIndex) {
    layer
        .setZIndex(zIndex)

    gridlayer
    // add the gridControl the active gridlayer
    var gridControl = L.mapbox.gridControl(gridlayer, {follow: false}).addTo(map);


    // Create a simple layer switcher that toggles layers on and off.
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    var link = document.createElement('a');

    link.href = '#';
    link.className = '';
    link.innerHTML = name;

    link.onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        if (map.hasLayer(layer)) {
            map.removeLayer(layer);
            map.removeLayer(gridlayer);          
            map.legendControl.removeLegend(layer.getTileJSON().legend);         

            this.className = '';
        } else {
            map.addLayer(layer);
            map.addLayer(gridlayer);          
            map.legendControl.addLegend(layer.getTileJSON().legend);          
            this.className = 'active';
        }
    };
    item.appendChild(link);
    ui.appendChild(item);
}
new L.Control.Zoom({ position: 'topright' }).addTo(map);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```